# Mathjax being parsed with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, mathjax

I have been trying for a while now to get MathJax to render properly using Jekyll.

I have tried several parsers (regular, `kramdown` and `redcarpet`) but none seem to do what I want. I have also tried all the solution mentioned here: [Using MathJax with Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987992/using-mathjax-with-jekyll)

The problem is that I am using rules to write down some equations. I have created a minimal working example using plain html, to make sure that my code is actually valid. You can see that here: http://call-cc.be/files/example.html

I just want to display that exact code (well, ill change it once it works) on my jekyll-generated website.

However, the parser is reading through the mathjax and complaining about liquid tags not being closed:

```
Configuration file: /Users/m1dnight/vcs/cdetroye.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/m1dnight/vcs/cdetroye.github.io
       Destination: /Users/m1dnight/vcs/cdetroye.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
  Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error: Variable '{{#1}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/ in /Users/m1dnight/vcs/cdetroye.github.io/_posts/2015-11-11-stlc.md
jekyll 3.0.1 | Error:  Liquid syntax error: Variable '{{#1}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
```

In addition to the solutions I tried mentioned above, I have tried putting the code in `{%raw%}` tags and that just rendered the actual mathjax code, including some `<p>` here and there.

Another solution I tried was this plugin I found, but again, to no avail. https://gist.github.com/jessykate/834610

The full post I am trying to render is shown below. Watch out, is rather lenghty.

```
---
layout: post
title: Work goddamnit
---

Foo bar bar


    <div>
    $$
    \newcommand{\lolli}{\multimap}
    \newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}
    \newcommand{\with}{\&}
    \newcommand{\all}[2]{\forall {#1}.\;{#2}}
    \newcommand{\fix}[2]{\mu {#1}.\;{#2}}

    \newcommand{\letv}[3]{\mathsf{let}\,{#1} = {#2}\;\mathsf{in}\;{#3}}

    \newcommand{\Fun}[2]{\Lambda {#1}.\;{#2}}
    \newcommand{\fun}[2]{\lambda {#1}.\;{#2}}

    \newcommand{\unit}{\left(\right)}
    \newcommand{\letunit}[2]{\letv{\unit}{#1}{#2}}
    \newcommand{\pair}[2]{\left({#1},{#2}\right)}
    \newcommand{\letpair}[4]{\letv{\pair{#1}{#2}}{#3}{#4}}
    \newcommand{\unita}{\left[\right]}
    \newcommand{\paira}[2]{\left[{#1}, {#2}\right]}
    \newcommand{\fst}[1]{\mathsf{fst}\,{#1}}
    \newcommand{\snd}[1]{\mathsf{snd}\,{#1}}
    \newcommand{\inl}[1]{\mathsf{inl}\,{#1}}
    \newcommand{\inr}[1]{\mathsf{inr}\,{#1}}
    \newcommand{\case}[5]{\mathsf{case}({#1}, \inl{#2} \to {#3}, \inr{#4} \to {#5})}
    \newcommand{\abort}[1]{\mathsf{abort}\,{#1}}
    \newcommand{\fold}[1]{\mathsf{in}\,{#1}}
    \newcommand{\unfold}[1]{\mathsf{out}\,{#1}}

    \newcommand{\judge}[4]{{#1};{#2} \vdash {#3} : {#4}}
    \newcommand{\judgetp}[2]{{#1} \vdash {#2} : \mathsf{type}}
    \newcommand{\judgectx}[2]{{#1} \vdash {#2} : \mathsf{ctx}}

    %% Rule names

    \newcommand{\rulename}[3]{{#2}{\mathrm{#3}}_{\mathrm{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\intro}[2][]{\rulename{#1}{#2}{I}}
    \newcommand{\elim}[2][]{\rulename{#1}{#2}{E}}

    \newcommand{\Var}{\rulename{}{}{Var}}
    \newcommand{\AllI}{\intro{\forall}}
    \newcommand{\AllE}{\elim{\forall}}
    \newcommand{\LolliI}{\intro{\lolli}}
    \newcommand{\LolliE}{\elim{\lolli}}
    \newcommand{\UnitI}{\intro{1}}
    \newcommand{\UnitE}{\elim{1}}
    \newcommand{\TensorI}{\intro{\tensor}}
    \newcommand{\TensorE}{\elim{\tensor}}
    \newcommand{\TopI}{\intro{\top}}
    \newcommand{\TopE}{\elim{\top}}
    \newcommand{\WithI}{\intro{\with}}
    \newcommand{\WithEFst}{\elim[fst]{\with}}
    \newcommand{\WithESnd}{\elim[snd]{\with}}
    \newcommand{\ZeroI}{\intro{0}}
    \newcommand{\ZeroE}{\elim{0}}
    \newcommand{\SumIInl}{\intro[inl]{\oplus}}
    \newcommand{\SumIInr}{\intro[inr]{\oplus}}
    \newcommand{\SumE}{\elim{\oplus}}

    \newcommand{\MuI}{\intro{\mu}}
    \newcommand{\MuE}{\elim{\mu}}

    \newcommand{\size}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
    \newcommand{\inferrule}[3][]{\frac{#2}{#3}\;{#1}}
    $$
    $$
    \boxed{\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A}}
    \\
    \inferrule[\Var]
              { }
              {\judge{\Delta}{x:A}{x}{A}}
    \\
    \begin{array}{cc}
    \inferrule[\AllI]
              {\judge{\Delta, \alpha}{\Gamma}{e}{A}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\Fun{\alpha}{e}}{\all{\alpha}{A}}}
    & 
    \inferrule[\AllE]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{\all{\alpha}{B}} \\
               \judgetp{\Delta}{A}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e\;A}{[A/\alpha]B}}
    \\[2em]
    \inferrule[\LolliI]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma, x:A}{e}{B}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\fun{x:A}{e}}{A \to B}}
    & 
    \inferrule[\LolliE]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A \to B} \\
               \judge{\Delta}{\Gamma'}{e'}{A}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma,\Gamma'}{e\;e'}{B}}
    \\[2em]
    \inferrule[\UnitI]
              { }
              {\judge{\Delta}{\cdot}{\unit}{1}}
    &
    \inferrule[\UnitE]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{1} \\
               \judge{\Delta}{\Gamma'}{e'}{C}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma,\Gamma'}{\letunit{e}{e'}}{C}}
    \\[2em]
    \inferrule[\TensorI]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A} \\
               \judge{\Delta}{\Gamma'}{e'}{B} }
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma,\Gamma'}{\pair{e}{e'}}{A \tensor B}}
    &
    \inferrule[\TensorE]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A \tensor B} \\\\
               \judge{\Delta}{\Gamma', x:A, y:B}{e'}{C}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma,\Gamma'}{\letpair{x}{y}{e}{e'}}{C}}
    \\[2em]
    \inferrule[\TopI]
              { }
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\unita}{\top}}
    &
    \\[1em]
    \inferrule[\WithI]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A} \\
               \judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e'}{B} }
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\paira{e}{e'}}{A \with B}}
    &
    \begin{array}{l}
    \inferrule[\WithEFst]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A \with B}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\fst{e}}{A}}
    \\[1em]
    \inferrule[\WithESnd]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A \with B}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\snd{e}}{B}}
    \end{array}
    \\[3em]
    \begin{array}{l}
    \inferrule[\SumIInl]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A }}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\inl{e}}{A \oplus B}}
    \\[1em]
    \inferrule[\SumIInr]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{ B}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\inr{e}}{A \oplus B}}
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{l}
    \inferrule[\SumE]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{A \oplus B} \\\\
               \judge{\Delta}{\Gamma', x:A}{e'}{C} \\\\
               \judge{\Delta}{\Gamma', y:B}{e''}{C} }
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma, \Gamma'}{\case{e}{x}{e'}{y}{e''}}{C}}
    \end{array}
    \\[3em]
    &
    \inferrule[\ZeroE]
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{e}{0}}
              {\judge{\Delta}{\Gamma}{\abort{e}}{C}}
    \end{array}
    $$
    $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
    $$
      \begin{array}{lcl}
        (\Fun{\alpha}{e})\;A                    & \mapsto & [A/\alpha]e  \\ 
        (\fun{x:A}{e})\;e'                      & \mapsto & [e'/x]e \\ 
        \letv{\unit}{\unit}{e'}                 & \mapsto & e' \\
        \letv{\pair{x}{y}}{\pair{e_1}{e_2}}{e'} & \mapsto & [e_1/x, e_2/y]e' \\ 
        \fst{\paira{e}{e'}}                     & \mapsto & e \\
        \snd{\paira{e}{e'}}                     & \mapsto & e' \\
        \case{\inl{e}}{x}{e'}{y}{e''}           & \mapsto & [e/x]e' \\ 
        \case{\inr{e}}{x}{e'}{y}{e''}           & \mapsto & [e/y]e'' \\ 
      \end{array}
    $$</div>

The end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have two problems here :

Liquid is parsing you code because of the brace. We make use of `{% raw %}{% endraw %}` tag.

Kramdown is also parsing your mathjax as code and embed it in

```
<div class="highlighter-rouge"><pre class="highlight"><code>
Your code here
</code></pre></div>
```

This is because your code is indented four spaces or more.
To avoid this you can remove indentation or make use of the `{::nomarkdown}{:/}` tag.

This definitely resolve this issue :

```
{% raw %}{::nomarkdown}
    <div>
    $$
    \newcommand{\lolli}{\multimap}
    \newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}
    ... More mathjax here
    $$
    </div>
{:/}{% endraw %}
```