# Using MathJax on a Github Page?

Tags: github, github-pages, mathjax

basic question here. I'm trying to figure out a simple and effective way of writing LaTeX-style formulas on a Github web page.

The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275645/how-to-supported-latex-in-github-pages) suggests that MathJax is a possible solution.

[This thread](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/256) seems to imply MathJax isn't supported.

Personally, I've followed the directions [Here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#secure-access-to-the-cdn)m but the math equations aren't appearing.

Thoughts?

Comment: It works with Jekyll so it can work with raw html on Github pages. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227995/mathjax-being-parsed-with-jekyll/34231579#34231579

Answer (score 6):

### 2022 Answer

MathJax is now natively supported when viewing `.md` files on GitHub. However, it is not automatically supported in GitHub Pages. To enable MathJax in GitHub Pages, the easiest option is to include the script from a CDN.

**TAKE NOTE**: *the CDN has changed*! The updated script tag to include is below. Add this script tag inside the `<head/>` of your `_layouts/default.html` file.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>
```

For more information, read [the MathJax Docs page about using a CDN](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html?highlight=cdn#using-mathjax-from-a-content-delivery-network-cdn).

#### Additional Help

If you want to use dollar signs (i.e. `$1 + 2$`) to escape math sequences, add the following as well:

```html
<script>
  MathJax = {
    tex: {
      inlineMath: [['$', '$']]
    }
  };
</script>
```

see [the docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html?highlight=cdn#configuring-mathjax) for more information.

Comment: Following [these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) did not produce a `_layouts/default.html` file. Assuming a new project from those instructions, what am I supposed to code?

Comment: You can look [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/) for information on how the layouts work with Jekyll. [Here](https://github.com/nullromo/kylekovacs/blob/main/_layouts/default.html) is a small example, and [the corresponding deployment](https://nullromo.github.io/kylekovacs/).

Answer (score 3):

you can use Mathjax on Github Page by adding next code in  tag in your html code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML,
https://vincenttam.github.io/javascripts/MathJaxLocal.js"></script>
```

I refered this page.
https://vincenttam.github.io/blog/2014/11/09/mathjax-local-configuration-file/

Comment: sorry, adding code is "https://vincenttam.github.io/javascripts/MathJaxLocal.js"   after https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML

Comment: The CDN has changed. Please see my answer for a more recent update.