# Using MathJax to render equations on a Jekyll blog hosted on GitHub

Tags: github, jekyll, mathjax

I am moving my blog from Wordpress to GitHub pages.  I used Barry Clark's instructions here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/ for getting started using Jekyll and GitHub Pages.  More specifically, I have forked the jekyll-now repository, renamed it, and have successfully served up a minimal working website at https://aaronmams.github.io.

I have added a simple first post but, after hours of reading SO posts and other blog posts, am still unable to include equations in a post.

Here is what I have done:

1. added the MathJax javascript to the file aaronmams.github.io/_layouts/page.html as suggested here http://gastonsanchez.com/opinion/2014/02/16/Mathjax-with-jekyll/
2. I also added the MathJax javascript to the file aaronmams.github.io/_layouts as was suggested here [Using MathJax with Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987992/using-mathjax-with-jekyll)
3. I added the following line to an existing post:

$$a^2+b^2$$.

I commit all changes and navigate to https://aaronmams.github.io/test and I can see that the quantity inside $$ $$ has not been printed.

4. I even tried adding the MathJax javascript directly to the post (test.md) as suggested by Carl here: https://github.com/cboettig/sandbox/blob/master/R-tricks/math.Rmd

I realize that some variant of this question has been asked many times.  However, I've read all the SO threads I could find and I'm no closer to getting equations rendered on my blog.

Can anyone offer some advice here?

Comment: embarrassingly, the problem has been solved.  I originally used:<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script> as the MathJax javascript...I needed https://....

Answer (score 1):

I changed the MathJax js link from

```
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
```

to

```
src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
```

and things are working great...I should have caught that earlier. sorry.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.