# Trouble rendering MathJax with Jekyll on github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, mathjax

I deployed a small blog at https://fiv0.github.io/ (Code at https://github.com/FiV0/FiV0.github.io).  I am using MathJax (with Jekyll) to generate some Latex but somehow GitHub pages does not render it correctly. None of the latex is displayed, but the source contains some code.
Locally Jekyll serves the site correctly.

I think it is some parsing issue as other people have had similar issues.
I looked at the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987992/using-mathjax-with-jekyll) question and have tried the answers there. 
There are also multiple blogs such as [this](http://georg.io/2013/11/how-this-page-was-made/) one discussing the issue. 
I have been to the [official doc](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#loading-cdn). All to no avail. It is probably some noobish mistake.

Comment: You are loading MathJax over http but your pages is (forced to) load over https, thus any browser will block the http call for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue.