# How to use MathJax in Jekyll in a details block?

Tags: jekyll, mathjax

I want to use the inline math formula from [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) in a Jekyll website inside a `details` tag.

Consider this block:

```
<details>
  <summary>Click to expand</summary>
  Function \\(f\\) leads to 

  $$ f(x) = x^2 $$ 

</details>
```

On my website I can view the `$$ f(x) = x^2 $$` part but inline formula does not work.

Comment: Please post a live sample.

Comment: Do you want a screen cast of the issue? but I can be reproduced by copying the above code example into a jekyll page

Comment: "copying the aove into a jekyll page" is not enough information  The HTML output migh thelp but it's not clear what you are expecting. If you're using kramdown then check its special syntax for inline equations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to enable *`\( \sum_{thing}^{done} \)`*, so far to enable in-line formatting with MathJax I've had to configure it to use *`$ \sum_{thing}^{done} $`*. Which I've tested using your above code (with some other adjustments) and found to be functional!

#### `./test.html`

```
---
layout: page
permalink: /test/
title: Test
---
{%- include mathjax.html -%}


<details><summary>Click to Expand</summary>
Function $f$ leads to
$$
  f{ \left( x \right) } = x^{2}
$$
</details>
```

> There's two versions for the `mathjax.html` `include`s...
>
> - Complex version can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352176/2632107) apart of an answer that shows how to *juggle* using CDNs on `production` and non-CDN `src`ing for non-production builds.
> - Simple version can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55509588/2632107) apart of an answer that shows how to set various MathJax settings within the include file's `<script>` tags.
>
> ... I'll not be re-posting'em but the simple version is available for [download](https://github.com/S0AndS0/python-graph-theory/blob/d8f91033013fcebb770aba8ebb9a7eba9b48c7a4/_includes/mathjax.html) from GitHub, just tap the `raw` button then `Ctrl^s` to save ;-)

This was tested using `kramdown` for the `markdown` interpreter along with `mathjax: true` set within a project's `_config.yml` file.

Some notes about the *`diff`* between the page code from the question and what I've posted

- `permalink` is **not** required and was only used for testing the body of the page's code.
- What's set for `layout` isn't important but without a `permalink` I believe that `title` becomes a requirement to have most layouts set cross-linking up correctly.
- I'm not tabbing in by **any** amount until within a multi-line formatted block, while the question's code was only tabbed in by two () spaces, and it generally takes four to trigger a `<code>` block, I don't want the markdown interpreter to even get a *whiff* of an *invite* to *muck-up* the markup desired.
- Using `f{}` (curly-braces around things having to do with `f`) *pulls* the parentheses a few pixels closer, not required for small stuff, however, it does make intentions that much more explicit for formatted and un-formatted versions.
- Using `\left( \sum_{thing}^{done} \right)` allows the height of parentheses to *grow* a little bit in height.

---

Hopefully some of these tips have allowed ya to get past this hurdle.