# MathJax doesn't support $

Tags: javascript, latex, jekyll, mathjax

```
<p>
    Test:
    When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
    $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</p>
<p>Step 1: Let $X_n$, $Y_n$ be the monotonically increasing coordinate array of every points in the field. And let
    subset $P \in$ whole points set $ Q$.</p>
<p>Step 2: Caculate the median of $X_n$ as $x_m$, let the vertical line $l$ at $x_m$ that bisects the point set $P$
    into two sets $P_L$ and $P_R$ such that $\lceil{P_L}\rceil$ means the left part of $P$, $\lceil{P_R}\rceil$ means
    the right part of $P$.</p>
<p>Step 3: Make two recursive calls in the $P_L$ and $P_R$ respectively, one to find the closest pair of points in
    $P_L$ and the other to find the closest pair of points in $P_R$. Let the closest-pair distances returned for $P_L$
    and $P_R$ be $\delta_L$ and $\delta_R$, respectively, and let $\delta = min(\delta_L,\delta_R)$.</p>
<p>Step 4: Caculate the points in the Area of $2\delta$ around $l$ to make sure whether exist one pair&#39;s distance
    $\delta'$ is less than $\delta$ in this area. If exist, then $\delta = \delta'​$, else, keep original one. </p>
```

[Different results of latex by mathjax in jekyll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbGwJ.png)

I post my blog by jekyll in github.io. And I use the mathjax script

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML" async>
</script>
```

to show the latex, but it seems that the mathjax does not support $...$ but \(.. \) in one page, Should I do more configure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MathJax with Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987992/using-mathjax-with-jekyll)

Answer (score 0):

[Ops, I just find the tutorial and it works.](https://cwoebker.com/posts/latex-math-magic)

Please add more configure in the < script\ >